# How to get listed in the share menu of the Photo App?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I know that in order to get my App listed under the share menu all I have to do is add the Document Types my App supports but it does not work for the "Photos App" for some reason, my App is never shown under this menu.
But if I send an image to my Email and then open it, then tap on Share and my App is right there, what type of document is required for the Photos App then? I added this so far:

`public.content`
`public.jpeg`
`public.png`
`public.heic`
`public.image`